# Kotlin - Parcelable Type mismatch: Required: String, Found: String?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, parcelable

The compiler is giving me the error `Type mismatch: Required: String, Found: String?` for the lines 
`parcel.writeString(firstName)` and `parcel.writeString(lastName)` inside the constructor of a Parcelable data class.

Here is my class.

```
data class Mouse(
val firstName: String,
val lastName: String,
val age: Int ) : Parcelable {
constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
    parcel.readString(),
    parcel.readString(),
    parcel.readInt()
)

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeString(firstName)
    parcel.writeString(lastName)
    parcel.writeInt(age)
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Mouse> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Mouse {
        return Mouse(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Mouse?> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}}
```

I don't understand why there is the error and how to correct it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, your error is caused by other lines. `parcel.readString()` returns `String?`, and you try to pass it to your primary constructor as `firstName` parameter which has `String` type. To fix it, you can, for example, pass a default value if returned string is null:

```
constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
    parcel.readString() ?: "",
    parcel.readString() ?: "",
    parcel.readInt()
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should insert `?:""` even if there are the lines`val firstName: String, val lastName: String,`?

Comment: Yes, because `parcel.readString()` returns a nullable type `String?`, and `firstName` has non-nullable type `String`, so you have to deal with null values.